# Get return value from void Async Method

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, wsdl, void

I have a Web Service (WSDL) and some void async methods (I can't change it to return Task) to call longer requests.

How can I get the result values from this methods?

On the Web Service, I have some EventHandlers, EventArgs (that I need to use on EventHandle delegate).

So the fundamental question it's, how can I clue all these things to get my results?

I have this, until now:

```
//Methods signatures
getSomethingCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, Exception, bool, object userState)
getSomethingCompletedHandler(object sender, Service.getSomethingCompletedEventArgs)

//Didn't build
Service srv = new Service()
srv.getSomethingCompleted += new getSomethingCompletedEventHandler(srv.getSomethingAsync);

//Other try
var args = new getSomethingCompletedEventArgs(null, new Exception(), false, "");
//Didn't build too (Method name expected)    
srv.getSomethingCompleted += new getSomethingCompletedEventHandler(args);


//This built, but I don't know how to get the results
public async static void GetSomething()
{
   await Task.Run(() => srv.getSomethingAsync(arg1,arg2,arg3));
}
```

Comment: `void` methods don't have return values, what do you think you can get from them?

Comment: Without a greater amount of surrounding information about what your app is actually doing, it's difficult even to understand your question.  When you make any asynchronous request, you must designate a "callback" that will eventually receive "events" that indicate success or failure.  In the various bits of code above marked "Other try" and so-on, it looks like you're stumbling in more-or-less the right direction, but haven't got it quite right yet, and gave-up much too soon.

Comment: DavidG, the calls that *issue* the requests might indeed properly be `void`, because *they* do not return a value.  Such values as may be "returned" will be provided, at some unknown future moment in time, when one of the expected events occurs.  The values will be part of the data that is supplied, along with the event, to those handlers.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I've searched a lot and I really think that "the other try" it's the right path... But I didn't realise yet what I'm missing...

Comment: Those "`+=`"s seem a little funny to me, but, "y'know, just Google It."  :-)  Surf until you find an existing, working example.  (On GitHub, maybe?)  Compare it side-by-side with yours.  That's gonna be a whole lot faster than whacking your head against it, when you're not yet familiar enough with the language to do things "instinctively."  Go *find* something that already works.  Stare at it.  Copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was missing a method to implement my callback and delegate it.

```
Service srv = new Service();

src.getSomethingCompleted += returnMethod;

Task.Run(() => srv.getSomethingAsync(arg1, arg2, arg3));

private static void returnMethod(object sender, getSomethingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = e.Result.items.ToList();
}
```

The return method are called when the getSomethingAsync receive the Completed status.